# printing structure element in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

```
(gdb) p/d &(((pcm_pkt_t*)0)->rx_timestamp)
$12 = 236
```

What does it actually print? Does it print the size of the `rx_timestamp` or its value?
This is from offline analysis from netbsd kernel.

Comment: This isn't actually a question about NetBSD -- it's a question about GDB (and somewhat about C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you get the address of a member of a structure which is located at address 0 (the `((pcm_pkt_t*)0)`). So you have the **offset** of this member inside the structure (member offset is address of the member - start address of the structure which is 0 here).

Comment: For what it is worth, this is the classic implementation of the C macro `offsetof` (casting it to `size_t`, of course).